# Why does SKNode() when assigned to a variable spawns an endless horde of enemies?

Tags: sprite-kit, nodes, swift5, xcode11

So I'm making a game where enemies fly past you and despawn when they die or leave the screen, and I was also making a play/pause button, and in order to do so I made a variable called worldNode and assigned it SKNode(). I made the variable inside no function but inside the GameScene class. Then every time I added something, I would do

```
worldNode.addChild(thing)
```

Since that allows me to pick and choose what gets paused and unpaused without freezing the whole game. But when I do it to these lines of code it spawns every enemy in at once, immediately killing the player. This code is from the update function.

```
if currentWave.enemies.isEmpty {
            for (index, position) in positions.shuffled().enumerated() {
                let enemy = EnemyNode(type: enemyTypes[enemyType], startPosition: CGPoint(x: enemyStartX, y: position), xOffset: enemyOffsetX * CGFloat(index * 3), moveStraight: true)
                worldNode.addChild(enemy)
            }
        } else {
            for enemy in currentWave.enemies {
                let node =  EnemyNode(type: enemyTypes[enemyType], startPosition: CGPoint(x: enemyStartX, y: positions[enemy.position]), xOffset: enemyOffsetX * enemy.xOffset, moveStraight: enemy.moveStraight)
                worldNode.addChild(node)
            }
        }
```

only for the addChild(node) does this happen, and I can't leave it out because then they keep flying around the screen. What would I do to fix this?

Comment: Where in your program is this code? dudBegin(), update() etc?

Comment: Edited question to include that, sorry

Comment: Details are still sparse, but here's a guess. You're using `currentWave.enemies.isEmpty` to check for the need for a new wave, and if so, then spawning some enemies and adding them to `worldNode`.  That's fine.  But if the wave isn't empty, then you're going through `currentWave.enemies` and adding a new enemy for every enemy that's already there (and of course swarming the player).  Probably the `else` part shouldn't be there, or you want to do something different there, like making the enemies fly around or shoot or whatever.